# wordpress rest api taxonomy return only 10

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

When I try to list terms from taxonomy with wp rest api i get only 10 items.
*eg. my-domain.io/wp-json/wp/v2/my_taxonomy/?*

In php, with `get_terms('my_taxonomy')`, i get all terms from this taxonomy.

It seems that WP limits the result from the rest api.

Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try updating the WP settings aboute post per page ? You could also try "post_per_page" or "showposts" with "-1" parameter in your get_terms arguments. See get_terms codex page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://v2.wp-api.org/reference/categories/) you need to indicate the number of items to show (default is 10)

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/my_taxonomy/?per_page=99
```